# Laravel collection: pluck before serialization

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a laravel Model with a one to many relationship which the user can edit via a multiple select tag.

Before exporting the model as a JSON, I use the "pluck" method to get an array of related IDs instead of an array of models, so that they can be used in the select tag and later be synced again with the "sync" method of Laravel.

However the result of "pluck()" seemingly doesn't persist over serialization. The following code doesn't work -upon serialization, "relationship" becomes again an array of objects-

`$model->relationship = $model->relationship->pluck('id');`

This one, however, does what it should: somePropertyIHaveJustCameUpWith is an array of IDs

`$model->somePropertyIHaveJustCameUpWith = $model->relationship->pluck('id');`

1) Why does this happen?

2) I have seen there is [this resources way](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources) in the documentation, but creating an entire new class for something that could be solved with a single line of code feels like a bit overkill. Isn't there a cleaner way to do that?

Comment: Could you convert this ->toArray() in order to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is likely a result of the way the model implements [toArray()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1074).

The you can trace the steps taken, but eventually the relations are read from the `$this->relations` property on the Model, not from each individual relationship.

So, instead of setting the value of your relation directly like:

`$model->relationship = $newValue`

... you could try setting it using:

`$model->setRelation('relationship',$newValue)`

This will update the `$model->relations` property.

This should allow the `toArray()` method to get the new value that you set when serializing.

Note that the `toJson()` method in turn calls the `toArray()` method when serializing. So either approach will be the same result.